# Python | check if dict{} item is in list[]

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

- Attempting to check an in-memory list, `plant_list[]` against a    `JSON` payload from an api.
- If the incoming payload's dict    `name` matches inside of `plant_list` the `if`  should fire off.
- Instead my script only returns `null`

  Please point out my    mistakes.

The  `JSON` sent over the api call is:
`{ "name":"swizz", "days": "7", "price": 2.00 }`

**Source Code**

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return 'Tiny'

plant_list = []
class Plant(Resource):
    def get(self, name):
        return {'Name':name}, 200

    def post(self, name):
        payload = request.get_json()
        for x in range(0, len(plant_list)):
            if payload['name'] == plant_list[x]['name']:
                return {'message': f'''Item {payload['name']} already stored in database.'''}
            else:
                plant_list.append(payload)
            return plant_list, 201


api.add_resource(Plant, '/plant/<string:name>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=9004, debug=True)
```

Comment: is the indentation for `return plant_list, 201` correct? Seems like it should be unindented

Comment: `plant_list` is always empty and your for loop is never executed. Additionally, you are changing a list while you are currently iterating over it - usually a bad idea.

Comment: This doesn't help your `null` issue, but for performance I would change `plant_list` into a `dict` keyed by `name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can test for key in dict simply by: `if key_name in my_dict:...`  So, `if "price" in plant_list[x]:`

Answer (score 0):

You are setting plant_list as a global.  If you want to use that inside a Class, you should define it inside the function in your class:

```
plant_list = []
class Plant(Resource):
    ....
    def post(self, name):
        global plant_list
        ....
```

Not sure why you need it as a global variable.  Perhaps you want:

```
class Plant(Resource):
    plant_list = []
    ....
    def post(self, name):
        ....
```